# beeline hive output without border lines

Tags: hive, format, hql, txt, beeline

I am currently getting my output to txt in the following format

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val | val | val | val |
| val | val | val | val |
| val | val | val | val |

I need this output without the border but with the column names so as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val | val | val | val |
| val | val | val | val |
| val | val | val | val |

I would also only like the column names to appear once at the beginning of the file

I have tried changing the configurations in the hql code by using:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=false;
```

this did not take care of the issue.

I also tried setting

```
set hive.cli.print.header=false; 
set hive.cli.print.footer=false;
```

but received the following error:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: hive configuration hive.cli.print.footer does not exists.
```

I also tried:

```
set hive.border.lines=false;
```

but got

```
Error: Error while processing statement: hive configuration hive.border.lines does not exists
```

Is there some other configuration I can use to get the desired format? The only other solution I have found online is to pipe the output to sed or tr to remove the + and - characters however this wouldn't be ideal due to the large data size.